# Subsequent calls to SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface fail with Access Violation when accessing IMG_Load from a member variable

Tags: c++, sdl

When stepping through the following the debugger encounters a SEGFAULT during the 2nd pass of `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`.

All I have been able to determine is that this may have something to do with pulling `IMG_Load` from a member variable. When I access `IMG_Load` directly instead of through `a->getSurface()` or when I return `IMG_Load` directly from `a->getSurface()` then this error doesn't occur.

The following fails:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

class Foo
{
    SDL_Surface* _surface;

public:
    SDL_Surface* getSurface()
    {
        return _surface;
    }

    void setSurface(SDL_Surface* surface)
    {
        _surface = surface;
    }
};

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("foo", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    Foo* foo = new Foo();
    foo->setSurface(IMG_Load("img.png"));

    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event e;

    while(!quit)
    {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,100,0,0,0);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_Surface* surface = foo->getSurface();
        SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, nullptr, nullptr);

        SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
        SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

        while(SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0)
        {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }

    delete foo;
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Changing `Foo` as follows evades the error:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    SDL_Surface* getSurface()
    {
        return IMG_Load("img.png");
    }

};
```

and the following succeeds as well:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,100,0,0,0);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

SDL_Surface* surface = IMG_Load("img.png");
SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, nullptr, nullptr);

SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);

SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
```

Comment: Nothing to do with member variables. Your code simply does different things. In the first bugged version you call IMG_Load once, and SDL_FreeSurface twice. But in the second version you call IMG_Load twice and SDL_FreeSurface twice.

Comment: One of the reasons experienced programmers say to be cautious about using `new` and `delete` is because it is hard to get the news and the deletes matching up exactly. Here you have the same problem except that its `IMG_Load` and `SDL_FreeSurface` instead of `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of first iteration you invoke `SDL_FreeSurface(surface);` making `SDL_Surface* _surface;` pointer stored in `Foo` class instance invalid as well. So on the next iteration `SDL_Surface* surface = foo->getSurface();` returns the same invalid pointer causing crash and / or  other nasty things associated with Undefined Behavior.